# Firestore returns empty snapshot on non-existent data with no internet

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore and RTDB behave very differently when attempting a listen without internet.  RTDB does not fire any listeners until internet is restored.  Firestore triggers a listener with an empty snapshot so a call to exists() returns false.  When internet is restored Firestore fires again with the live data.  This is an application without disk persistence and the fields/documents being read have never been written to prior to the listeners being set.

What firestore does can make things very confusing...  It might not be possible to tell whether the data really doesn't exist or something else went wrong.  Is this the intended behavior and is there some way around this?

```
//first firestore statement in the app
fs.collection("blabla").document("blabla").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error)
    {
        if (error == null)
            Log.v("TEST", "FS LISTEN EVENT " + value.exists() + " " + value.getData());
        if (error != null)
            Log.v("TEST", "FS LISTEN ERROR " + error);
    }
});
```

Logcat:

V/TEST: FS LISTEN EVENT false null

After internet restored:

V/TEST: FS LISTEN ERROR com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

**EDIT:**

I've tested this now with and without persistence.  Identical behavior at least for the first time this data is fetched. As I don't intend to use disk persistence this will happen every time the activity is created.

I can use get() instead of a snapshot listener - it returns a nice com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: Failed to get document because the client is offline.  Very different behavior.  But I have reservations about get() as well:

1. No way to stop/unregister it.  So I can't implement a timeout for this op. It can trigger when the app is paused - or at any other unexpected moment.  There is no goOffline with firestore...  Yes I could come up with logic to deal with it - sure is complicated though...
2. Never got the answer as to whether the coldfire issue has been resolved.  Some people recorded 90 seconds for get() to fetch data.  For some critical piece of data needed when the app boots, and no way to implement a timeout - how to deal with app flow?

Comment: "RTDB does not fire any listeners until internet is restored" That depends on how you write your code. Without seeing the code you use in RTDB, it's meaningless to compare the two databases, and I'd recommend making your question just about Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're seeing is normal, and expected.

Security rules are only enforced on the server, and not on the client-side cache.

The logic here is that for reads, since the client saw the data at some point, it continues to be visible. For writes it is a matter of allowing a fast update to the UI. If you want you can show that the write is pending by reflecting the [`hasPendingWrites`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SnapshotMetadata#hasPendingWrites()) in your UI.

What happens here is is:

1. The client commits the write to its local cache
2. The client fires local events for the write operation, so that the app can update its state.
3. The client sends the write to the server
4. The server rejects the write operation, and sends a negative response to the client.
5. The client updates its local state, and fires reconciliatory event(s) to ensure the app can also update its state.

Comment: I agree if that piece of data was ever written to locally the listen would return something.  But this is the first time that listen is executed on the client - there is nothing in memory, cache or otherwise.  It doesn't exist and never existed.  I could implement a timeout if nothing is returned and let the user know something went wrong.  But if it returns null - do I assume it had internet when it fetched this?  Does the data exist at all?  Gets complicated for the app flow at that point...

Comment: The thing is - it also returns an empty snapshot when it has internet and the document doesn't exist...  How to tell them apart?

Comment: You could [call `get()` with a source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#get(com.google.firebase.firestore.Source), forcing it to try and retrieve the data from the server. But the user experience won't be ideal.

Comment: get() does the job - it simply fails if it can't get data from the server.  I want max 5 seconds to either get the data or fail - and move on with the app flow.  The only thing is unlike RTDB there doesn't seem to be a way to unregister the get() call.  So there is the corner case where it doesn't fail - but takes forever and returns data at some point. So I guess I can just add logic that ignores the data after 5 secs.  I also have to handle the case if the app pauses, listeners executes, app resumes.

Comment: With RTDB I quickly solves this with a wrapper class for all the listeners and added timeouts with callbacks.  If the app pauses all listeners are unregistered.  When app resumes the listeners are added again with the appropriate amount of timeout left.  Seems clean compared to this...  I kinda wish Firebase initially supported timeouts for single get ops...

Comment: I would also like someway of being able to distinguish a returned null snapshot when the doc doesn't exist and a null snapshot when some network error occurred.  Is there some way?  Also, it seems if persistence is enabled and you get an initial null snapshot because of some network problems then subsequent null snapshots don't trigger the listener at all.  This is even if internet is restored but the doc doesn't exist, or you don't have permission.  So it may be difficult to detect these scenarios and respond accordingly.

Comment: 1) I'd recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for the inability to cancel `get()` calls, as I've been hit by that too. 2) The ability to specify/configure the timeout for that call sounds like a good feature request too. 3) If there is a way to distinguish between the two cases you describe it'd have to be in the snapshot's metadata.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to detect if the null snapshot returned was due to network issues by looking at the snapshot metadata (Frank's suggestion).  If persistence is disabled, no writes were executed to that location and a null snapshot is returned, but the metadata.isFromCache() returns true then I think it can be assumed that Firestore simply couldn't get the data from the server.  Conversely if metadata.isFromCache() is false then the document does not exist.

```
fs.collection("users").document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addSnapshotListener(MetadataChanges.INCLUDE, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error)
            {
                if (value != null)
                    Log.v("TEST", "FS LISTEN EVENT, exists: " + value.exists() + " data: " + value.getData() + " from cache: " + value.getMetadata().isFromCache());
                if (error != null)
                    Log.v("TEST", "FS LISTEN ERROR " + error);
            }
        });
```